# How to use optional in Dart for null safety

Tags: flutter, dart

I found this package that implements Optional for Dart: https://pub.dev/packages/optional/example

On the examples, it does things like this:

```
void filterExample() {
  final hello = Optional.of('hello');
  final world = Optional.of('world');
  final name = Optional.of('harry');

  for (var o in [hello, world, name]) {
    final filtered = o.filter((v) => v.startsWith('h'));
    print(filtered.isPresent);
  } // prints "true", "false", "true"
}
```

But how do I force a variable to be Optional of some type? I wanted to have `Optional<String>`, `Optional<int>`, etc, but I'm forced to give a value in the beginning.

The closest I can think is

final anEmpty = Optional.ofNullable(null);

which is already in the example, but what is a `Nullable`? If I do like this, I cannot constraint the value to be a `String` or `int`, it can be changed to anything. I want to stick to strong typing while using Optional.

If this is not possible with this library, then how can I make my own simple Optional type that supports templates so I can have `Optional<String>`, `Optional<int>`, etc?

Comment: Why can't you constrain the value when using the `ofNullable` constructor?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore if I use `final var something = ofNullable(null)` then `something` can be an Optional of anything, can't it? I can set it to an String or int.

Comment: What's preventing you from doing that

Comment: @ChristopherMoore I don't get it. I don't want to do that. If I create `String myString`, then I want `myString = 3` to be impossible. I want to do the same for optional: if I do `final Optional<String> myOptional` then I want to make it impossible to do `myOptional = Optional.of(3)`

Comment: Optional<int> o = const Optional<int>.empty();

Comment: i hope this what you are looking for because i've never used this package

Answer (score -1):

The behavior you are looking for (doing something if null and something else otherwise) can be achieved using the `??` operator.

This is basically a null check which equals the left hand if not null and right hand if null. Example: `doSomething(myString ?? "Default value of my string");`

Does this answer your question? Sorry, I haven't used that package and don't see a need to.